# Custom validator formArray controls

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a formGroup, the controls of this formGroup are formArrays,

my plan is to loop over the value of the formGroup.formArrays and check to see if any of the values are set to true, if so everything is ok.

But what is happening is; it's always invalid

```
 static validate (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null  {
    let isChecked = false;
    const tempArray = [];
      for ( let i = 0; i < control.value.length; i++ ) {
      const val = control.value[i];
      tempArray.push(val);
      }
   isChecked = tempArray.find( el => el === true );
   if ( isChecked ) {
    return null;
    }
    return  {
      'isNotChecked' : true
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the returns the wrong way around..
i.e. If it's invalid return null.

If you were following the Heroes in docs. there's double negatives..

```
** A hero's name can't match the given regular expression */
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

forbidden - because it can't match Regex.

(regex test would return true for a match)

Here's one of my examples:

```
export function min(min: Number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      const input = control.value,
      isValid = input < min;
      if(isValid) 
          return { 'minValue': {min} }
      else 
          return null;
    };
}
```

Let me know if this helps.