# Validation of Angular Reactive forms for invisible controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am struggling to find an answer to the following:
I am using `Angular Reactive forms` and as far as the validation is concerned I imagine something very simple like:

```
this.fb.group({"tel": [null, Validators.required]})
```

The problem is that if the corresponding UI element connected to the above Form Control is not visible, the form is not valid:

```
(errors: {required: true})
```

However, the bigger problem is the above behaviour is not the same for all the Form Controls. For some others, there is no problem in the case where they are not visible and they do not make the form invalid. ***Is there something that could differentiate the behaviour***? For me, there is no difference in the above controls!!

Comment: Can you disable the control when it's not visible, and enable it if it is?

Comment: How are you making the tel control invisbile?

Comment: I am using *ngIf

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could add a custom validator, that emulates required but accomodates whenever a property of your component indicates a field is hidden too. I am not sure if there is a better alternative. Let others add their two cents.

Comment: Duplicate of this. Should have Googled: "required validator with hidden fields in angular" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967360/angular-2-form-validation-on-hidden-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ngIf It will not exclude the formControl from the formGroup. If Use {disabled:true}  then the formControl will be excludes from the form Group , Then you can use enable method to enable it as per your requirement.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      "tel": [{disabled: true, value: null} , Validators.required],
      check : true
    })
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/condi-control-disabled