# Getting error in validation while submitting the form

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a form, inside the form
I'm showing a textbox on selecting the dropdown
I'm calling a form array, where i get multiple textboxes.
When i submit my form is showing invalid even when i give values for all fields.

```
  
           
                        
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type" formControlName="type">                                      

                        <select class="Dropdown" formControlName="category" >
                            <option >Select Category</option>
                            <option  *ngFor="let list of dropdownitems" [value]="list.id" >{{list.name}}</option>
                        </select> 

                    <ng-container *ngIf="optionValue == '3'">
                                               
                          <input type="text" formControlName="listItem" class="form-control" placeholder="enter dropdownlist items"> 
                        <small class="errormessage" *ngIf="submitted && addForm.controls.listItem.hasError('required')">
                            Category is required 
                        </small>
                          <a (click)="addGroup()">Add New Textfield</a>

                    </ng-container>
                    
                     <span formArrayName="times" *ngFor="let time of addForm.controls.times?.value; let i = index;">                          
                      <span [formGroupName]="i">                         
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lists" placeholder="enter dropdown options">  

                      </span>
```

In ts i'm validating all the fields.
onSubmit() function, if the form is invalid i'm showing an alert.
Please correct my code and help me achieve this functionality.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z# ]*')]],
      times: this.formBuilder.array([])
      }); 
    console.log(this.addForm.value);
  }

public dropdownitems = [{
    name: "A",
    id: 1
  },{
    name: "B",
    id: 2
  },{
    name: "B",
    id: 3   
  },{
    name: "D",
    id: 4    
  }]

  onSubmit(){
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.addForm.invalid) {
      alert ('Please fill up complete details');
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.addForm.value);   
}


value = this.formBuilder.group({
  lists: ['', Validators.required],
});


addGroup() {
  const val = this.formBuilder.group({
    lists: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  const form = this.addForm.get('times') as FormArray;
  form.push(val);
}

removeGroup(index) {
  const form = this.addForm.get('times') as FormArray;
  form.removeAt(index);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even if the fields are hidden in the template (`HTML`) they are defined in the form as `required`.

You need to either add and remove the form fields conditionally or you need to make them `enabled` / `disabled` to ignore the `required` flag.

Sharing [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3i6ggx?file=src/app/app.component.ts) the fixed Stackblitz with a possible solution and small improvement (removed the `ngModel`

You have a similar issue raised on this thread
[form validation on hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967360/angular-2-form-validation-on-hidden-fields/51379633)

Comment: First step, did you understand why you are having the issue?

Comment: Check this answer in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/51379633/9019541  you need to enable or disable depending on your selection

Comment: Yes because the problem is that your value is not 3. Is C. Your dropdown values are letters. Try changing it to compare with C instead of 3.

Comment: Can you please put a console.log(category) inside value.changes to printout the value you are receiving? I’m trying to check it on the phone but stackblitz doesn’t work great on a phone

Comment: OK. Which number? Do you ever get a 3? Also you are doing another mistake. When using reactive forms you don’t need [(ngModel)]. That might also be messing up the detection of changes and creating conflicts. You’re mixing two approaches: template based (with ngModel) and reactive forms ( with formControlName)

Comment: OK I’ll have a look when I’m back on the computer and I will help you.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The value is being sent as string (of course) from the form field. I did a few changes also to remove the `[(ngModel)]` on that particular spot, for your reference. You can then apply the same type of logic wherever you need. Have a look and let me know if you understand the changes https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3i6ggx?file=src/app/app.component.ts